# Tensorflow slower when using multiple threads during preprocessing on CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a dataset that is generated on the fly on the CPU. Samples are computed in python by a function `make_sample` that is pretty complex and *cannot* be translated into tensorflow ops. Because sample generation is time consuming, I want to call the function from multiple threads to fill an input queue.

I started from the [example given in the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data#batching) and arrived at the following toy example:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import time

def make_sample():
  # something that takes time and needs to be on CPU w/o tf ops
  p = 1
  for n in range(1000000):
    p = (p + np.random.random()) * np.random.random()
  return np.float32(p)

read_threads = 1

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
  example_list = [tf.py_func(make_sample, [], [tf.float32]) for _ in range(read_threads)]
  for ex in example_list:
    ex[0].set_shape(())
  batch_size = 3
  capacity = 30
  batch = tf.train.batch_join(example_list, batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity)

with tf.Session().as_default() as sess:
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
  try:
    # dry run, left out of timing
    sess.run(batch)
    start_time = time.time()
    for it in range(5):
      print(sess.run(batch))
  finally:
    duration = time.time() - start_time
    print('duration: {0:4.2f}s'.format(duration))
    coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
```

What surprises me is that, when increasing `read_threads`, the CPU usage never goes above 50%. What's worse, the computation time plummets: on my computer,

- `read_threads=1` → `duration: 12s`
- `read_threads=2` → `duration: 46s`
- `read_threads=4` → `duration: 68s`
- `read_threads=8` → `duration: 112s`

Is there an explanation, and above all, a solution to get efficient multithreaded data generation with custom python function on tensorflow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tf.py_func` reuses existing Python interpreter. Unfortunately Python supports concurrency but not parallelism. In other words you can have multiple Python threads, but only one can execute Python code at any time. Standard solutions are to move generation pipeline into TensorFlow/C++, or use multiple Python processes and additional layer to aggregate their results (ie, aggregating results from multiple Python processes using ZMQ)